# why can't I highlight the link i am currently on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I basically has a side bar navigation with a couple of links. I want to be able to highlight the appropriate link according to the page I am on.

for some reasons, my code doesn't seem to be working.

here's the html file:

```
<div class='sidebar'>
                <div class='title'>
                    Sonder
                </div>
                <ul class='nav'>
                    <li><a class='active' href='members.php?view = <?=$user?>'>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href='members.php' >Members</a></li>
                    <li><a href='friends.php' >Friends</a></li>
                    <li><a href='messages.php'>Messages</a></li>
                    <li><a href='profile.php'>Edit Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

here's a part of the css:

```
.nav li a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav li a:before {
    font: 14px fontawesome;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 20px;
}
.nav li:nth-child(1) a:before {
    content: '\f015';
}

.nav li:nth-child(2) a:before {
    content: '\f0c2';
}

.nav li:nth-child(3) a:before {
    content: '\f183';
    left: 23px;
}

.nav li:nth-child(4) a:before {
    content: '\f003';
}

.nav li:nth-child(5) a:before {
    content: '\f013';
}

.nav li:nth-child(6) a:before {
    content: '\f023';
    left: 22px;
}

.nav li a:hover {
    background: #444;
}

.nav li a.active {
    box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 #5b5, inset 6px 0 0 #222;
    background: #444;
}
```

here's the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setNavigation();

});

function setNavigation() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);

    $(".nav a").each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues in your code.

1. The `path` JS variable is having a preceding forward slash, i.e. `/members.php` or `/friends.php`. For this reason, the `path.substring(0, href.length)` part is returning like `/members.ph` which doesn't match with any hrefs in the page.
2. The active class that highlights the menu, is on the anchor tag element, not in the li tag element as per the CSS you wrote, but with the JS you tried to add the active class to the li.

Here is a complete snippet that worked:

**HTML:**

```
    <div class='sidebar'>
        <div class='title'>Sonder</div>
        <ul class='nav'>
            <li><a class='active' href='members.php?view=<?=!empty($user)?:0?>'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='members.php' >Members</a></li>
            <li><a href='friends.php' >Friends</a></li>
            <li><a href='messages.php'>Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href='profile.php'>Edit Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .nav li a {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #eee;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nav li a:before {
        font: 14px fontawesome;
        position: absolute;
        top: 14px;
        left: 20px;
    }
    .nav li:nth-child(1) a:before {
        content: '\f015';
    }
    .nav li:nth-child(2) a:before {
        content: '\f0c2';
    }
    .nav li:nth-child(3) a:before {
        content: '\f183';
        left: 23px;
    }
    .nav li:nth-child(4) a:before {
        content: '\f003';
    }
    .nav li:nth-child(5) a:before {
        content: '\f013';
    }
    .nav li:nth-child(6) a:before {
        content: '\f023';
        left: 22px;
    }
    .nav li a:hover {
        background: #444;
    }
    .nav li a.active {
        box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 #5b5, inset 6px 0 0 #222;
        background: #444;
    }
```

**Script Block:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           setNavigation();
        });

        function setNavigation() {
            var path = window.location.pathname;
            path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
            path = decodeURIComponent(path);

            $(".nav a").each(function () {
                var href = $(this).attr('href');

                if (path.substring(1, path.length) === href) {
                    $(".nav a").removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

This should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I moved your code around a bit and made the jquery work, not sure how well it will work in the snippet so here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/wysh0j6q/

```js
 

$('document').ready(function() {
  setNavigation();
});

function setNavigation() {
  var path = window.location.href;
  path = (path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));

  $(".nav .menu").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (path === href) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #eee;
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav li a:before {
  font: 14px fontawesome;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  left: 20px;
}

.nav li:nth-child(1) a:before {
  content: '\f015';
}

.nav li:nth-child(2) a:before {
  content: '\f0c2';
}

.nav li:nth-child(3) a:before {
  content: '\f183';
  left: 23px;
}

.nav li:nth-child(4) a:before {
  content: '\f003';
}

.nav li:nth-child(5) a:before {
  content: '\f013';
}

.nav li:nth-child(6) a:before {
  content: '\f023';
  left: 22px;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background: #444;
}

.nav li a.active {
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 #5b5, inset 6px 0 0 #222;
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js'></script>
<div class='sidebar'>
  <div class='title'>
    Sonder
  </div>
  <div class='nav'>
    <li><a class='menu' href='#'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a class='menu' href='#'>Members</a></li>
    <li><a class='menu' href='#'>Friends</a></li>
    <li><a class='menu' href='#'>Messages</a></li>
    <li><a class='menu' href='js'>Edit Profile</a></li>
    <li><a class='menu' href='#'>Logout</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS rules are executed on order, your `active` class overrides the hover.

Change position and it should work

```
.nav li a.active {
    box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 #5b5, inset 6px 0 0 #222;
    background: #444;
}
.nav li a:hover {
    background: #444;
}
```

Or add a specific `active:hover` rule

Answer (score 0):

Change css rule to

```
.nav li.active a{}
```